# Weird positioning of elements when div contains text

Tags: css, css-position

I have this problem where I have some containers that need to be aligned in a parent container, but for some reason that does not happen.

This is how it looks like:

http://jsfiddle.net/pV6EV/1/

This is what happens if I remove the labels from top and bottom (removing this pieces of code `<div class="eticheta">top</div>` and `<div class="eticheta">bottom</div>`)

http://jsfiddle.net/pV6EV/2/

As you can see the div with class l34 is positioned correctly in the second example, but I need to have the labels inside it too.

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its because you are using `inline-block;` in class that why element is not aligning properly just add `vertical-align:top;` in `.134 class` it will fix it

http://jsfiddle.net/pV6EV/5/

Answer (score 1):

one thing I tried was changing the display property of l31 and l24.
if you give them

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace:

```
.l31 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

With:

```
.l31 {
  float:left;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/pV6EV/4/

Comment: @mugur i dont used float and i fixed it

Comment: @Hushme I have seen that. Is there any problem with browsers in using "float"?

Comment: that you have to use float on other element too and some time they cause clear problem

Comment: @mugur - The problem with using float is that if you've got several elements on a line, to keep the order of elements you've got to float everything on that line. Then you've lost all the benefits of the line box layout - vertical-align, text-align:justify, etc. It doesn't usually matter, but if you get too reliant on floats it can limit your options.